# Possible to access LocalMachine cetificates in MY store using SunMSCAPI?

Tags: java, certificate, certificate-store

Is there an Oracle reference somewhere that clearly states that you cannot access the LocalMachine certificates in the MY store using the SunMSCAPI provider?

Thanks,
Bert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We proved this by using the free Microsoft/Sysinternals tool PSExec.exe.

By running the same Java program as either a regular user or a system user, we could determine the regular user could not obtain the LocalMachine certificate.

The command:

PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe

Then run the Java program in a console the regular way with java.exe. You can display the current user in the Java code with getEnv("USERNAME").

Interestingly, a system account cannot access a current user's registry setting from Java either.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your particular error, there is a bug reported [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6931562)

Comment: Thank you for that link, but it doesn't mention LocalMachine.