# Access Windows Local Machine Personal Keystore with Java (SunMSCAPI)

Tags: java, windows, certificate, client-certificates, mscapi

Is there a way to access the windows **local machine** personal key storage with Java using *SunMSCAPI*?

Usually, you can use either **WINDOWS-ROOT** (which is roughly the equivalent to the trusted storage in Java) or **WINDOWS-MY** (which contains the personal certificates which is roughly equivalent to the key storage in Java) to retrieve certificates from the windows certificate storage.

This works fine for users, but even when impersonating the SYSTEM user, I was not able to retrieve the local machine's personal certificates.

There exist [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193143/use-jna-to-get-local-machine-certificate) questions regarding this that [use JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612962/access-local-machine-certificate-store-in-java) (which I would like to avoid, especially since it seems to be complicated to retrieve the private key from there).
Also, someone [used psexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788143/possible-to-access-localmachine-cetificates-in-my-store-using-sunmscapi) to impersonate the SYSTEM user (using *psexec -s*). I also tried this, but have not been successful.
In the end, there is also an [open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6782021) in the Java Bug System.

If anyone has an idea on how to retrieve certificates from the local machine personal storage in windows using Java, I would be grateful.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612962/access-local-machine-certificate-store-in-java/51708360#51708360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

After fourteen years in the bug tracker, [JDK-6782021](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6782021) was finally fixed in Java 19 (Spring 2022). This means this is no longer an issue.

---

### Original answer

Yes *and* no. You can use [the `wcsa` utility](https://github.com/oddbjornkvalsund/wcsa), which will intercept JVM calls to the Windows Crypto API and let you access the local machine credentials. This is of course a hack around the real problem, [JDK-6782021](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6782021), which was reported ten years ago. But it does let you access the local machine certificates in a pretty painless way!

So yes, it is possible to access them, but no, it's not possible to access them using the plain Java API. You *can* access them using normal Java using the commercial product [JCAPI](https://pheox.com/products/jcapi/), though, but for most uses the `wcsa` util is fine.

[The Open JDK maintainers are willing to take a patch, though](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6782021), so maybe you can have a stab at fixing it using the code provided in the `wcsa` repo :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up using C# for this task, because in my case, intercepting JVM calls is just too hacky in production...

Comment: Seems like [JDK-6782021 It is not possible to read local computer certificates with the SunMSCAPI provider](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021) has been resolved and will be available in Java 19. `Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE` & `Windows-ROOT-LOCALMACHINE`

Comment: Thanks for the links ;-) Saved me a lot of time. Bug in jdk is fixed with 11.0.18 (20 for oracle) and 17.0.5 (7 for oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that works independent of the Java version and whether or not https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021 or https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313367 are fixed. It uses a small Powershell script to dump the certificates to a temp folder where Java can read them in easily.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class WindowsCertificateService {
    private static List<X509Certificate> getWindowsLocalMachineCertificates(String certType) {
        // Theoretically we could use KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT-LOCALMACHINE") and
        // KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE") to accomplish this, which were added as part of
        // https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021. Unfortunately, we'll get an Access Denied error due to
        // https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313367.

        Path tempFolder;
        List<X509Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("seeq-link-getWindowsLocalMachineCertificates");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Log an error if desired
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        try {
            String powershellScript = String.format("dir cert:\\localmachine\\%s | Foreach-Object { [system.IO" +
                    ".file]::WriteAllBytes(\".\\$($_.Thumbprint).cer\", ($_.Export('CERT', 'secret')) ) }", certType);
            Path scriptLocation = tempFolder.resolve("getWindowsLocalMachineCertificates.ps1");
            Files.write(scriptLocation, powershellScript.getBytes());
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-File", scriptLocation.toString());
            processBuilder.directory(tempFolder.toFile());
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            process.waitFor();
            if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
                // Log an error if desired
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            Collection<File> cerFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(tempFolder.toFile(), new String[] { "cer" }, false);
            for (File cerFile : cerFiles) {
                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cerFile)) {
                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(fis);
                    if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                        certificates.add((X509Certificate) cert);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log an error if desired
                }
            }
            return certificates;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Log an error if desired
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } finally {
            if (tempFolder != null) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempFolder.toFile());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log an error if desired
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `certType` argument can be either `"root"` or `"my"`.